# how to count specific word in a listview column

Tags: vb.net

I have a form which is 1 list view and a text box.

 * list view has a total of 100 rows of data

 * list view has 5 columns

 * column 3 has only two possible words `yes` or `no`

I want to count the number of occurrence of the word `yes` in column 3

the total row can be count with this code:

```
''''''''''COUNT TOTAL ADMISSION''''''''''''''

Dim rowcount As Integer = 0

For Each item As ListViewItem In LVfeestatementBA_I.Items
  rowcount = CInt(item.SubItems(0).Text) 'Considering every column always have some value
Next

txttotaladBA_I.Text = rowcount.ToString()
```

any help will be greatfull

**EDIT 1**

This is a school assignment. As I said my aim is to find out the number of occurrence of a word in column 3. I have database of MS access which is connected with code and provides the data for the list view. The list view has 5 columns and there are a total of 100 rows. The data in col-3 contains only three words `gen`, `occ`, and `cc`. Now in want to count col-3 for the words with code and show the number like (68) in `textbox1`

**EDIT 2**

I applied the function provided by thedarkspoon, but it's not showing the result. I just want the result to be shown in `textbox1`, ex. if total number of words are `78` then at the time of `form_load` it should show `78` in `textbox1`. I solved the problem by adding at last `textbox1.text = numofyes` and change variable from `integer` to `string` now its working

Comment: Its cool to ask for help here but go easy with hassling people to fix your problem urgently as this is free website.

Answer (score 1):

I did not quite understand your scenario (you have to be more clear).

Anyway, given a ListView that displays items that each have 3 subitems and we know that the third subitem will have values of either "yes" or "no" we can build a query like (using linq):

```
     var collectionOfListViewItems = listView1.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>();
     var numberOfrowsWithTheThirdSubItemTextEqualToYes = (from c in collectionOfListViewItems where c.SubItems[3].Text == "yes" select c).Count();
```

Without linq you could do a foreach:

```
     var numberOfrowsWithTheThirdSubItemTextEqualToYes = 0;
     foreach (ListViewItem  item in listView1.Items)
     {
        if (item.SubItems[3].Text == "yes")
           numberOfrowsWithTheThirdSubItemTextEqualToYes++;
     }
```

Comment: thanks for your reply Ando,sorry for not clearing my point because i am fully new to use visual basic 2010 and trying to make a prog. 4 my school.the problem is not solve yet as i said my aim is to find out d number of occurrence of a word in column 3 i have database of ms access which is connect with code. now from where the data is depicting in list view. list view has total 5 columns) total row are 100 with data col-3 contains only three words "gen","occ" and "cc" now in want to count col-3 for the words with code and show the number likes(68)in textbox1.please solve my problem thanx agian

Answer (score 1):

Ok here you go, I made this a function but you could easily adapt this to a subroutine:

```
Function countyes()
    'Set up a variable to count the number of yes:
    Dim numofyes As Integer = 0
    'Count the number of yes (Replace listview1 with the name of your listview):
    For Each item As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items
        'If the Yes/No is in column 3, you are looking in subitem 2:
        If item.SubItems(2).Text = "Yes" Then
            'Increment the variable by one if the value is yes:
            numofyes = numofyes + 1
        End If
    Next
    'Return our total number of Yes that we found:
    Return numofyes
End Function
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for response, i apply the function but its not showing result.as you see the question i just want the result must show in the textbox1, that is if total number of words are 78 then at the time of form_load it should show the result in the textbox1.i will also apply your function if permissible for counting other words. kindly help me

Comment: Glad it's all working! And of course you can use it to count other words, just replace the word Yes in the 'if' statement with the word you want to count. Glad I could help :)

Comment: hi thedarkspoon,can u help for this also,see the code: Dim numofgeneral As String = 0
        
        For Each item As ListViewItem In LVfeestatementBA_I.Items
            If item.SubItems(3).Text = "GENERAL" & item.SubItems(4).Text = "MALE" Then
                'Increment the variable by one if the value is yes:
                numofgeneral = numofgeneral + 1
            End If
        Next
       
        txtgencategoryBA_I.Text = numofgeneral "it is giving me error "Conversion from string "MALE" to type 'Boolean' is not valid" help for this thanks in advance